# How to pass indefinite amount of arguments to a function in different programming languages

Tags: function, functional-programming, parameter-passing

I use the proprietary [Wolfram Language](https://www.wolfram.com/language/)™. Now I feel I must migrate to a more general purpose programming language. One very important feature I looked for in other programming languages while going through several tutorials is how to pass an indefinite amount of arguments to a function. This peculiarity is apparently not covered in basic tutorials (at least not the ones I've seen). The task is ridiculously straightforward in the Wolfram Language™:

```
Function[x]:=x; (*Function defined with one argument.*)
Function[x__]:={x}; (*Function defined with indefinite amount of arguments.*)
Function[{x__},{y__}]:={x}+{y}; (*Function defined with indefinite amount of arguments of two different "types".*)
(*Etc.*)
```

Until I figure out how to do this (among other things) in some other commonly adopted programming languages (C, C++, Java, Python, Ruby, Perl, and so on), I won't be able to decide which one to learn next.

Is it prudent to ask for a compendium on how to fulfill this task in other programming languages?

Comment: I think this question is a bit too broad for stackoverflow. Our Q&A format works best for questions that have a single correct answer, and doesn't work very well for open ended lists (how to do X on all programming languages) or opinion-based questions (what language should I learn next)

Comment: If you think that's an important feature, then you have a bit of learning left to do, because in many languages the deterministic aspect of function arguments means you typically *don't* want to do that. If you're using Wolfram, you're probably used to those inputs being things like vectors of data. Every language in existence lets you do that with typed arguments like array, list, vector, hashes, etc. Instead of finding the perfect next candidate, just pick one and start reading up on how it's used, and what best practices are, and _why_.

Comment: In most programming languages it is more customary to have functions that operate on lists/arrays instead of functions that receive an arbitrary number of arguments. Instead of doing `sum(1,2)` and `sum(1,2,3)` you would do `sum([1,2,3])`. The function receives a single parameter, which is a list with multiple elements.

Comment: @hugomg Technically, I'm not asking which language should I learn next. That's only my explicit motivation for knowing this. I think many viewers would appreciate to see what I ask for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are known as [variadic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). Not every language supports them, they're not an important feature - usually you just pass an array/list/vector (or whatever standard ordered collection type there is) as a single argument, which is simpler and more practical in many regards.

The [German Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadische_Funktion) and the [Rosettacode topic](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Variadic_function) have many examples in different programming languages.

Comment: The worst examples are in C and C++.

Comment: @RichardSantiago as many are telling you, it doesn't matter if a language supports this or not. Every non-toy language can write a program that interacts with an unknown number of values...

Comment: @naomik Well, it obviously matters to ME. Otherwise, I wouldn't mind even asking. Don't you think? Geez.